# How Kick out telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How we can kick out a telegram BOT from groups?
I'm developing a telegram bot using Telegram bot API to kick out other bot added to group.

Comment: Get new chat member info , if new chat member,s username end whit bot kick out

Answer (score 2):

if you set group privacy of your bot off via Botfather, your bot will get new messages in the group as updates. upon joining a new user you will get a json message in your handler and you can check if it is a bot or not by checking `msg.new_chat_member.is_bot` value. then you can use kickChatMember API of bots to kick out that user.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete your own bot , i think there is no way but asking the main admin of group(or others that can delete members)

But if you want to delete the bots that join to your groups you can use below code(IN PHP):

```
function send_reply($url, $post_params) {

    $cu = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   //get result
    $result = curl_exec($cu);
    curl_close($cu);
    return $result;
}
$kickchatmember_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot[Bot-TOKEN]"."/kickChatMember";

$update = file_get_contents("php://input");

$update_array = json_decode($update, true);

$newchatparticipent = $update_array["message"]["new_chat_participant"];
$chat_id = $newchatparticipent["id"];
$bot_or_not = $newchatparticipent["is_bot"];

if($bot_or_not == 'true'){
     $kick_post_prs = array('chat_id' => $Group_id , 'user_id' => $chat_id);
     send_reply($kickchatmember_url , $kick_post_prs);
}
```

And Here We Go!